# Android: "Fatal Exception" calling getInputStream() on a URLConnection when using Google Maps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-activity

Thanks in advance for the help!

I put together a request to maps.googleapis (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?) and call it using the following code

```
this.myURL = new URL(mapsUrl);
URLConnection conn = myUrl.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
return in;
```

The chain events that lead to this line of code are set off in onPostResume in MainActivity.java (I've also tried running it in onActivityResult initially, that didn't work, so I tried onPostResume instead, but both result in the same error).

The error message is provided below

```
03-14 02:07:52.123: W/dalvikvm(28964): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f88ba8)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964): Process: com.example.BTManager.local, PID: 28964
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.BTManager.local/com.example.BTManager.local.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.directions.route.XMLParser.getInputStream(XMLParser.java:29)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.directions.route.GoogleParser.parse(GoogleParser.java:32)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at com.example.BTManager.local.MainActivity.onPostResume(MainActivity.java:630)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5323)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
03-14 02:07:52.223: E/AndroidRuntime(28964):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to load data in the main Thread

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You must do all the network related operations in some Worker Thread.

Learn from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).

Thanks.